# Include whole folder in VSIX

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Is there an easy way to include a whole folder as content in a VSIX package? Hopefully there is an easier way than setting the "Include in VSIX" flag for each file separately.

The reason why we need this, is to add a compiled html help page (with a lot of dependency files) to our extension.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: The suggested solution works, but each time I change something to the solution, Visual studio replaces the wildcards with separate entries for each file.

Comment: Indeed, this is an known issue about Visual Studio, you can check my previous thread for some more details:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282527/preventing-visual-studio-from-rewriting-project-references, if you want to delete some files, you can use `Exclude=""`

Comment: The solution works only partly, as now and then the files are expanded in the csproj file. Maybe somebody else has a better solution. For that reason I will leave this question unresolved. But thanks for your help!

Comment: You are always welcome :).

Comment: @TWT How are you accessing your bundled content in code? I've got my file included in the package, but am struggling to find how to load it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to include a whole folder as content in a VSIX package? Hopefully there is an easier way than setting the "Include in VSIX" flag for each file separately.

You can use wildcard `*` to include all the files under the folder as content into the VSIX package, like:

```
<Content Include="TestFolder\*.*">
  <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
</Content>
```

After build the VSIX project, change the generated file `.vsix` to `.zip` and unzip it, we will find all the files in the `TestFolder`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could have mentioned where Content goes.  Please don't assume the knowledge of your audience.

Answer (score 1):

As an extra idea to the answer above: since `.vsix` is a regular `.zip`, you can unzip it, put your files inside, zip it back and rename into `*.vsix` - this will still work as a regular VSIX installer.

So the entire solution for building a `vsix` installer with additional files (e.g. output of other solution builds):

1. Add a folder, e.g. `Resources` to your `vsix` project
2. Put "blob" files included into this vsix project into this folder and set these options in `Properties` window:

```
    BuildAction = Content
    Inclide in VSIX = True
```

3. Mention desired additional file extensions in csproj like that:

```
    <Content Include="Resources\*.json">
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Resources\*.dll">
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Resources\*.exe">
      <IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>
    </Content>
```

4. Put any dummy file with each extension (each mask mentioned in csproj) into this folder  - so VS will understand that related option in `csproj` is not a broken/dummy string and will not ignore files with this extension later
5. Build the VSIX solution
6. Grab `myproj.vsix` file
7. Rename it into `myproj.zip`, unzip
8. Copy any files you need (with extensions/masks mentioned in `csproj` file) into `Resources` folder
9. Zip all the stuff back into `myproj.zip`, rename it into `myproj.vsix`
10. There you go: **VSIX** installer with a bunch of additional files needed for your installation. Install it.
11. Put your VS version into this path and go there:

```
    cd %AppData%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\
```

12. Locate your extension under subfolder named like `3xg44004asdf` and check `Resources` subfolder contents - your files are there. Except files/file masks not mentioned in csproj even if they exist inside VSIX installer.

This scenario can be useful for building extensions for internal needs with TeamCity-like runner:

1. Build VSIX dependencies
2. Build VSIX
3. Embed dependency artifacts into VSIX as described above
4. Supply modified VSIX